# App crashes everytime crash code provided below

Tags: android-studio

05-03 04:47:23.906 6489-6489/com.example.alondra.positive1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.alondra.positive1, PID: 6489
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alondra.positive1/com.example.alondra.positive1.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.alondra.positive1.LoginActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.alondra.positive1.LoginActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                                Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.alondra.positive1.LoginActivity
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
                                                                                        ... 14 more
                                                                                Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex file '/data/app/com.example.alondra.posit

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @AbhilashMaurya what code exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Activity Register

XML

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>     android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
>     android:text="Positive + 1"
>     android:textSize="30sp"
>     android:padding="20dp"
>     android:textColor="@color/Black" />
>
> <EditText
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
>     android:maxLines="1"
>     android:id="@+id/etEmail"
>     android:hint="Email"
>     android:textColorHint="@color/Black"
>     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
>
> <EditText
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:id="@+id/etPass"
>     android:inputType="textPassword"
>     android:hint="Password"
>     android:textColorHint="@color/Black"
>     android:maxLines="1"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
>
>
> <Button
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:id="@+id/btnReg"
>     android:text="Register"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>     android:onClick="register"
>     />
>
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>     android:text="Back to Login"
>     android:id="@+id/tvLogin"
>     android:textColor="@color/Black"
>     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>     />
> ```

Java

> package com.example.alondra.positive1;
>
> import android.content.Intent; import
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle;
>   import android.view.View; import android.widget.Button; import
>   android.widget.EditText; import android.widget.TextView; import
>   android.widget.Toast; 2
>
> public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
>   View.OnClickListener {
>       private Button reg;
>       private TextView tvLogin;
>       private EditText etEmail, etPass;
>       private DbHelper db;
>       @Override
>       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>           setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
>
> ```
>     db = new DbHelper(this);
>     reg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnReg);
>     tvLogin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLogin);
>     etEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
>     etPass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPass);
>     reg.setOnClickListener(this);
>     tvLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
>
>
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onClick(View v) {
>     switch (v.getId()) {
>         case R.id.btnReg:
>             register();
>             break;
>         case R.id.tvLogin:
>             startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
>             finish();
>             break;
>         default:
>
>     }
> }
> private void register(){
>     String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
>     String pass = etPass.getText().toString();
>     if (email.isEmpty() && pass.isEmpty()){
>         displayToast("Username & Password Fields are empty");
>     }else {
>         db.addUser(email,pass);
>         displayToast("Your account has been created succesfully");
>         finish();
>     }
> }
>
> private void displayToast (String message){
>     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
> } }
> ```

Comment: As you Error log suggests that the LoginActivity class is not at the location specified or is not present.